# Folland Theorem 1.18 Explanation for the Set Construction

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, intuition

I shall state the statement of Theorem 1.18 and the proof here:
[image]

In particular, I am wondering if Folland is allowing the possibility that the constructed set $K$ is empty. I do not see why we can not have the containment $\overline{E} \subseteq U$. Note that if the containment is established, it must be strict containment as $U$ is open and $\overline{E}$ is closed and thus $K$ has to be empty.

Comment: Without even considering your questions, something is off about that proof.  Which edition and printing is this?

Comment: @BrianMoehring This is the second edition of Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications by Folland. I believe it is the most recent edition on the market? I have not posted the complete proof where he later extended the case to general set $E$ without assuming boundedness if that is part that seems off?

Comment: No.  It was the inequality $\mu(E) \leq \sum_1^\infty \mu((a_j,b_j))+\varepsilon$ which is true but useless.  It's corrected [in this errata](http://www.math.washington.edu/~folland/Homepage/oldreals.pdf).  I just have a mind to get stuck on that type of point, so I couldn't get to your question yet (I'll try now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sufficiently large $\varepsilon$ it may be possible for $K=\emptyset$, but the only way to have $K=\emptyset$ to satisfy $\mu(K) \geq \mu(E) -\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$ is if $\mu(E) = 0$ in the beginning.  (this is certainly allowed but it's really the trivial case for the corresponding equality involving the supremum)

Otherwise, if we choose $\varepsilon < \mu(E)$ then the "excess" $U$ covers outside of $\bar{E}\setminus E$ cannot cover all of $E$ as well, so then $\bar{E} \subset U$ would be impossible as $E\not\subset U$.